# Undelete a question (without URL, it doesn't appear in my profile)

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I accidentally deleted a long question I just posted on Stack Overflow. I am trying to recover it, but I can't find it in my profile or activity list anywhere and do not have the URL.

It was titled something similar to "(Java) Call Method of a Class Without Knowing the Class Name"

Where am I supposed to look to find this and undelete it? Answers to similar questions seem to suggest the question should still be listed in my profile somewhere, but I don't see it...

Comment: Well, not yours, but this one might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000489/how-to-call-method-without-knowing-the-class-name

Comment: I remember seeing a question like that so pretty sure it was properly submitted. Unfortunately I don't know about in-deleting, but thought you'd like the reassurance it was posted.

Comment: If you ask a mod (in a flag, or on the chat), nothing obliges and also nothing forbids them to show the link to you. I typically don't annoy the mods with this. In the very rare cases as I asked this from them, they were helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of your question list (in your profile, click on the Activity tab at the top then click on the questions tab below the grey boxes), there is a link that says "deleted recent questions" which will list all your questions which are both deleted and asked within the past 60 days.

Comment: Okay, that is very odd.  The question I am looking for isn't there.  I was positive I got confirmation the question was posted successfully.  Apparently not? Should I have gotten an email about the question being posted?

Comment: There is notification of it being posted, as it gets posted the moment you click the submit button. Have you tried clicking the Ask Question button to see if it is currently saved as a draft and never got submitted? If it's not there, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @ani Maybe you could look at the Zephyr's profile and find that question?

Comment: @niceal I did, there's no such question.

Comment: @nicael in case the question was never submitted (which is likely the case here), there's nothing to see in the profile, even for SE developers. Maybe they can check the draft cache, though not sure it will exist even there.

Comment: @Sha Oh, but I thought it was submitted. Ok then.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I am now at work (a different computer) and I logged in to post my question.  It was loaded in the New Question window for me automatically.  This didn't happen on my home computer (where I made my first attempt to post).

Comment: @Zephyr It gets stored in local storage via JavaScript, in case the server deletes it before you get back to it. So you'll still have a local copy.